# Which implemantation of which path search algorithm would be the fastest in my scenario?

Tags: c++, c, path-finding

I am looking for a path search algorithm which will allow me to find the shortest route between known points A and B which are nodes, and those are connected to other nodes.

In my case there are around 20,000 nodes of which each can have a maximum of 16 connections (links) which are directed (by this I mean, if node A is connected to node B, it doesn't mean that node B is connected to node A, this is for right-lane driving and left-lane driving, ment for highways)

To avoid problems, here is an image of what I mean with connections (along with directed):

[image]

Example map:
[image]

From A to D the shortest route here would be A->C->D and from D to A it would be just D->A

I know all the distances between each link and no distances are negative.
(Because I know all the XYZ positions of my nodes)

In short:

-What would be the fastest algorithm in C or C++ (I can use both) for my case?

-ofcourse I need to retrieve the route but I also need to (calculate/ or) retrieve the distance from point A to point B)

-Is there a library available for my needs

-Optionally: is there a library with multi threading (support) for this (if yes, which one)?

-Are there any code examples available?

Why I ask this question is because I want to improve some code which is very slow. I want to do it by rewriting the code because currently Dijkstra is used and not ment for this situation.

The code which I currently use is here:

https://gpb.googlecode.com/files/RouteConnector_180.zip

Also here is a example usage in real life of the code:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EHj7GavsbqQ&t=40

Comment: 20k nodes? 16 possible routes? sounds too many possible combinations

Comment: 16 connections to each other node form one node

Comment: What do you mean by "Dijkstra is used and not ment for this situation"?

Comment: Also, if there is an embedding of the graph to 3d space, then the Euclidean distance between nodes is a lower bound on the length of the shortest path and you can use A*.

Comment: By this I mean that I know where both points are and dijksrtra calculates the distance form A to every other node, which makes it do more work than needed.

Comment: Note about your code: there is bunch of not-so-fast operations, like erasing from std::vector, checking inList inside double loop...

Comment: @avakar +1 for A*. A single-pair shortest path algorithm is not likely to be any faster than Dijkstra, so the best bet is to limit the search space. With a solid heuristic like the Euclidean distance, A* should perform quite well.

Comment: Any example A* implementation for my case / graph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [Dijkstra algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra_algorithm). Also [Boost::Graph](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/graph/doc/index.html) has [implemented](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/graph/doc/dijkstra_shortest_paths.html) it.

Comment: "For a given source vertex (node) in the graph, the algorithm finds the path with lowest cost (i.e. the shortest path) between that vertex and every other vertex. It can also be used for finding costs of shortest paths from a single vertex to a single destination vertex by stopping the algorithm once the shortest path to the destination vertex has been determined."

Comment: I would suggest using the A* search from boost

Answer (score 2):

A* has been proven to be the fastest pathfinding algorithm possible for the general problem.